# Function not mocked in jest and uses actual implementation

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have the following setup

firebase.client.ts

```
import * as config from 'config';
import * as firebase from 'firebase-admin';

/**
 * Abstracts the initialization and direct use of Firebase.
 */
export class FirebaseClient {
    static initialized = false;

    static initialize() {
        if (!FirebaseClient.initialized) {
            const firebaseConfig: any = config.get('firebase');
            firebase.initializeApp({
                credential: firebase.credential.cert(JSON.parse(firebaseConfig.privateKey)),
                databaseURL: firebaseConfig.databaseUrl,
            });
            FirebaseClient.initialized = true;
        }
    }
}
```

auth-preprocessors.ts

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase-admin';
import { Errors } from 'typescript-rest';
import { logger } from './logger';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { FirebaseClient } from './firebase.client';

/**
 * @see https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/custom-resource-backend
 * @param message
 */
export async function requireAppCheck(req: Request) {
    FirebaseClient.initialize(); // Initialize FirebaseClient
    doSomeStuff();
}
```

I have authentication.controller.ts

```
import { Inject } from 'typescript-ioc';
import { PATCH, Path, Preprocessor } from 'typescript-rest';
import { requireAppCheck } from '../utils/auth-preprocessors';

@Path('/')
@Security('apiKey')
export class AuthenticationController {

    @Path('v1/path')
    @PATCH
    @Preprocessor(requireAppCheck)
    public async myFunc(
    ): Promise<Response> {
        return await doSomething();
    }
}
```

And in authentication.controller.spec.ts
import * as config from 'config';
import { Container } from 'typescript-ioc';
import * as AuthProcessors from '../utils/auth-preprocessors';
// rest of the imports

```
describe.only('PATCH /path', () => {
    let requireAppCheckMock: jest.Mock;


    beforeEach(() => {
        requireAppCheckMock = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('someValue');
        jest.spyOn(AuthProcessors, 'requireAppCheck').mockImplementation(requireAppCheckMock);
    });

    it.only('does stuff', async () => {
          const response = callController();
          expect(response.status).toBe(200); 
    }
```

With this setup, I get the error below, which means that requireAppCheck is not being mocked correctly, and it uses the actual implementation (since it tries to call `FirebaseClient.initialize`)

*text: '{"status":500,"error":"Internal server error","stack":"SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input\n    at JSON.parse ()\n    at Function.FirebaseClient.initialize (/path/to/firebase.client.ts:14:59)"}'*

I also tried doing

```
    jest.mock('./../utils/auth-preprocessors', () => ({
        requireAppCheck: requireAppCheckMock
    }))
```

But I get the same result.

#### EDIT

It looks like that the main issue I have is that the requireAppCheck is used in that @PreProcessor (which acts as a middleware), because when I use it inside the `myFunc`, the mock is used. Still, I am not sure how to mock it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The `PreProcessor` is a factory method that will be loaded immediately by the  `AuthenticationController`. This means that you need to hook its mock outside, very early in the spec file.

```
import * as authPreProcessor from '../utils/auth-preprocessors';
let requireAppCheckMock = jest.fn();
jest.spyOn(authPreProcessor, 'requireAppCheck').mockImplementation(requireAppCheckMock);
// rest of your imports
```